# Unable to edit text in footer area

Tags: footer

[image: Screen capture of problematic footer section]

Hello!

I have a problem with editing the footer section of a Magento installation. Basically in the bottom right corner, there is a section of text, the one labelled as Company Information. And it might sound stupid, but I just can't find the file or section in either CMS or Configuration where that particular text can be edited.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled template hints, and see what hint it gives for that block?
If you cannot find this in the code/templates, it is most likely a static block, or admin configurable values. You best bet is to use template hints, and work backwards from there.

Comment: It was very well hidden in a custom static block. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I placed the comment as an answer so the question can be closed off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled template hints, and see what hint it gives for that block? If you cannot find this in the code/templates, it is most likely a static block, or admin configurable values. You best bet is to use template hints, and work backwards from there.